# Angular ngOnInit testing subscription

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular2-observables

I am trying to test a simple call that goes to my dialogueService and returns an observable. When the method is fired a local property on my component is set. My code is below. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have tried everything I cannot get it to work at all.

**Dialogue.component.ts**

```
export class DialogueComponent implements OnInit {
  public showDialogue: boolean;
  public reason: string;

  constructor(private dialogueService: DialogueService) { }

  public closeDialogue() {
    this.showDialogue = !this.showDialogue;
  }

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.dialogueService.showDialogue.subscribe((shouldShow: boolean) => {
      this.showDialogue = shouldShow;
    });
    this.dialogueService.reason.subscribe((reason) => {
      this.reason = reason;
    });
  }
}
```

**Dialogue.component.spec.ts**

```
describe('DialogueComponent', () => {
  beforeEach((() => {
    resetSpies();

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [DialogueComponent],
      imports: [RouterTestingModule],
      providers: [DialogueService]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should set the subscriptions and update the component properties accordingly', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DialogueComponent);
    const dialogueService = TestBed.get(DialogueService);
    spyOn(dialogueService, 'showDialogue').and.returnValue(Observable.of({ foo: 'bar' }));

    // I have used a tick() here using fakeAsync but no luck either

    expect(fixture.componentInstance.showDialogue).toEqual(false);
  }));
```

});

Comment: The component isn't calling a method to get the observable, so spying isn't going to work. Why not use the DI's other options (specifically `useValue`, see https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action) to pass in a test double instead of the real service? I'd recommend reading the testing guide, which has many examples: https://angular.io/guide/testing

Comment: But the ngOnInit gets called internally? I see it getting called, and in then it should call my service..

Comment: `ngOnInit` will get called, but it *doesn't* call anything on the service, it subscribes to some observable properties. Again, create a test double; you can then get direct access to e.g. a subject you can push test data into to exercise the logic.

Comment: ah I understand! Thank you Jon!